# Getting totalminutes without decimals

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
timeSpent = endTime - startTime;
msgArea.Items.Add(timeSpent.Hours + " Hours");
```

I want it to return minutes as integer, insted of decimals.

I tried  Convert.ToInt32(...), but not allowed.
Right now it will return  0.0023304343 as an example, if it is less than 1 min. I want it to just say 0 minutes
Thanks in advance

Comment: `I tried Convert.ToInt32(...), but not allowed.`? Why?

Comment: I don't understand what is decimal here.. Timespan properties are all integer or long...

Comment: How do you know that `timeSpent` is of `Timespan` type? Maybe it's custom class. It looks like `Timespan` but we don't know at all :)

Comment: Assuming this is TimeSpan, it supports custom formatting as of .NET 4.0...

Comment: Are you sure you want `TotalMinutes`? This can go over 60.

Comment: @Selman22: `TimeSpan` properties are not all `int`s, the `Total...` properties return a `double` since they represent the whole and fractional units. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You just need to cast it if you're not interested in the decimal places:

```
decimal d = 0.0023304343m;
int i = (int)d;
```

But i assume that you want to format your `TimeSpan` as this:

```
string output = string.Format("{0} Days, {1} Hours and {2} Minutes"
    , (int)timeSpent.TotalDays
    , timeSpent.Hours
    , timeSpent.Minutes);
```

As you can see there are `Total...` properties which return the total amount of the unit as double and `Hours`/ `Minutes` etc.  properties which return an integer. The difference is:

- `TotalHours` for example can be 36.1234
- `Hours` is always an `int`, the part of the day, `Minutes` the part of the `Hour` etc

It's worth noting that since .NET 4 you can also use `ToString` with a format string since `TimeSpan` implements `IFormattable`. I just find it difficult to remember how to escape it properly:

```
string output = timeSpent.ToString(@"hh\:mm"); // for example
output = timeSpent.ToString("d' Days, 'h' Hours, 'm' Minutes.'"); // your example
```

Comment: In your format, since `TotalDays` is a `double` that already includes the hours and minutes part, as fractional days, you want to modify something.

Comment: Also note that since .NET 4.0, `TimeSpan` supports format strings, so you could do e.g. `timeSpent.ToString("d' Days, 'h' Hours, 'm' Minutes.'")`.

Comment: Thanks for noting, i've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Math.Floor`:

```
var hours = (int)Math.Floor(timeSpent.Hours);
```

Comment: Is the `.Hours` property not already of type `int`? In that case the above code is meaningless.

Comment: We don't know. There is no any information, that `timeSpent` is `TimeSpan` instance. It looks like `TimeSpan`, but maybe it's external / custom class where `Hours` is of `decimal` type.

Comment: So your answer assumes (with no mention of it) that `timeSpent.Hours` is a `double` (or `decimal`)? In that case it might be easier to write just `var hours = (int)timeSpent.Hours;` **EDIT:** It works differently (better) on negative numbers, similar to `Truncate`.

Comment: Yeah, it might be easier to write as you mentioned. However, in my opition it's clearer to explicity get floor. Other programmer (let's say that won't know how it works) that read code will know exactly what's going on :)

Comment: @pwas: since he's using `timeSpent = endTime - startTime;` it's _very_ likely that he's subtracting two `DateTime`s which returns a `TimeSpan`. Although  he's showing a  bad example since `timeSpent.Hours` doesn't return a `decimal` value but an `int`.